# How can I implement an accordion style menu?

Tags: java, android

How can I create an accordion style menu in Android as seen [here](http://www.scriptocean.com/accordion.html)?

I have tried with the `ExpandableListView` but it does not provide the same look and feel. Is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: ehi.. any news? have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any android view components for this purpose. You may have to create a custom view by yourself.